# sencha touch :: how to create list of hbox-items

Tags: list, toggle, sencha-touch

i want to generate a list of data out of a store. each data item holds a title and a boolean. now i want to have a list of the items, each holding the title and a togglefield (showing the boolean) on the right of the title.

how could I do that?

thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Sencha Touch documentation, a List is "a mechanism for displaying data using a list layout template", i.e. html template. If you want a 'list' of components, you'll have to make your own extension of DataView (I think).

A workaround could be to put an html checkbox inside your itemTpl.
Something like (warning - not tested):

```
itemTpl: '<p>{title}: <input type="checkbox" name="BoolCheckbox" class="boolcheckbox"'
    + "{[(values.bool? 'checked="checked"' : '')]}"
    + '></input></p>'
```

To run your own code in the XTemplate, you bracket it with {[]}. When in this scope, you have access to a variable 'values', which contains the data for the record.

To detect events, you'd add a listener to the list:

```
itemtap: function (dataView, index, item, e) {
    if (e.getTarget().getClass().toString() == "boolcheckbox") {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Some resources on templates:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/

http://www.sencha.com/learn/xtemplates-part-i/

http://www.sencha.com/learn/xtemplates-part-ii/

Comment: hey, thx! yes, i thought about using html in a template but then you loose to possibility to slide the togglefield with your finger. you only could click-touch it then.

Comment: seems that there is no other way. would be happy if you pass your code, if you ever will make the way back to your office.
:-)

Comment: oops, sorry, busy day & forgot :) I edited the answer to show how to access the bool.

Comment: sorry :/. I know the format of {[]} works for me, so play around with that. To debug, try setting itemTpl to just '{[(values.YourBool)]}', see what happens. If you get a true/false value, then you know you have the right data and can work on getting the conditional formatted right.

Comment: oh, just noticed I had put in the ternary operator a comma instead of a colon. that would definately mess it up *facepalm*